# How to store category name with vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I want to create a simple category with vue.js and laravel 5.7 for first. And I tried to do those hours but I did not succeed

How to save name with vue.js?

> **Tip:** I do not see any errors. I want to save the name in the database.

index.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('categories.store') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" v-model="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sub_category">Sub Category:</label>
        <select id="sub_category" v-model="parent_id" class="form-control">

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" @click="addCategory()" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        name: "",
        parent_id: ""
    },
    methods: {
        addCategory: function () {
            axios.post('/admin/store', {
                name: this.name,
                parent_id: this.parent_id
            }).then(response => {

            }, response => {
                this.error = 1;
                console.log('Errors')
            })
        }
    }
});
```

CategoryController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Category::create([
        'name' => $request->name
    ]);

    return response('Category created', 201);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function (){
    $this->get('panel', 'PanelController@index')->name('panel.index');
    $this->resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain where the problem come ? Which error is returned ?

Comment: more details please

Comment: I want to save `name` in `parent_id` and I want to create a subcategory.